# How can I instruct apt, not to make EFI changes

Tags: apt, uefi, grub-efi

I have Ubuntu installed on a USB stick, which is plugged into an otherwise fully functioning machine.  When I boot to the USB stick (using a manually configured EFI boot entry for the USB stick) and run apt-get upgrade, all I want it to do, is update the contents of the USB stick, and not make changes to my EFI (BIOS), as when it does, it tends to mess with the other manual entries I have in there.

How do I instruct apt-get upgrade (or possibly grub-update), to not make EFI changes?  I'm totally ok with new grub entries in the boot menu on the USB stick, but I don't want to have to restore the EFI each time.

To further explain, I have Kubuntu 20.04LTS installed on my SSD, and Kubuntu 18.04LTS installed on my USB stick.  When I run apt upgrade from either, periodically it will wipe my EFI list and replace it with a single entry 'ubuntu' pointing to the device I ran upgrade on.  I then have to replace that with a new entry called either Kubuntu 20.04LTS or USB Kubuntu 18.04LTS.  However I'd rather it just left me EFI list well alone, and focused on /dev/sda or /dev/nvme0n1 where grub is installed, and left it at that.  The running OS never interfered with my Boot list, when it was BIOS.  I'd like each OS to leave alone the other, or my ability to boot to it.

Comment: You should have an ESP on external drive. And then set fstab to use that ESP. Then internal drive should be set as second in default boot & flash drive as first in default UEFI boot. And copy /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu from internal drive's ESP to external drive. Updates may change boot order, but that is easy to reset.